# Retryable not works in separate thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, junit, spring-retry

I am trying to test, if my method call was retried several times if some exception takes place. And if I call method directly, it works okay. But if I call it in separate thread, my test method fails it doesn't see any retry attemps. 
That's my methods:

```
public class MyClass {
        @Inject
        private ServiceClass service;

        @Retryable(value = {Exception.class}, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 30000))
        public void retryMethod(Integer id, double dId)
        {
            Thread remoteDIUpdater = new Thread(() -> {
            service.updateIndex(id, dId);
            }
            );
        remoteDIUpdater.setDaemon(true);
        remoteDIUpdater.setName("RemoteDIUpdaterThread");
        remoteDIUpdater.start();
        }

        @Recover
        public void recover(Exception ex, Integer id, double dId)
        {
            logger.error("Error", ex);
        }
}
```

And this is my test class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    @Inject
    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Mock     
    private private ServiceClass service;

    @Test
    public void testMethod()
    {
        Integer id = 1;
        double dId = 2d;
        doThrow(Exception.class).when(service).retryMethod(id, dId);
        myClass.updateBetDangerIndex(betId, dangerIndex);
        verify(service, Mockito.times(5)).retryMethod(null, id, iId);
    }

}
```

Maybe my test method is wrong. BUT if I call my method simply like this (withot thread):

```
@Retryable(value = {Exception.class}, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 30000))
            public void retryMethod(Integer id, double dId)
            {             
                service.updateIndex(id, dId);              
            }
```

, my test method runs ok. What is the mistake?

Comment: Your test is wrong. You are mocking things and creating a new instance yourself (basically the `@Inject` is useless) and as such `@Retry` will do nothing.

Comment: I am using test spring context and inject works well. My test works good withput multithreading.

Comment: No it doesn't... The `@InjectMocks` renders the `@Inject` useless as it will construct a new instance and inject the mocked dependencies into it. It will not use the instance injected by Spring. Hence your test is just wrong.

Comment: I simplyfied my code and maybe made a mistake or not mentioned smth. The problem is not in @|nject or smth like this. Don't know how to test such multithreaded app.

Comment: Yes it is the problem... the `@Retry` works with AOP, which is applied through Spring. As you are using `@ InjectMocks` you get a new unproxied instance. Basically you get a `new MyClass()` here without anything AOP applied. So again your test is wrong.

Comment: Why does it work good without threads?

Comment: The problem with threads is they don't wait, they execute in the background. You would basically have the same problem in your live production code. Instead you should be using `@Async` and implement another way of doing the retries.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to add Thread.join() after remoteDIUpdater.start() to prevent the main thread from finishing before your thread.

Comment: with this method is called only once.

Comment: Why do you assume that retryMethod will be called 5 times ? maxAttempts = 5 but it doesn't mean that retryMethod will be called 5 time

Comment: doThrow(Exception.class).when(service).retryMethod(id, dId); - because of this.